# File not formatting after saving in Sublime even when SublimeAstyleformatter's autoformat_on_save is true

Tags: c++, macos, formatting, sublimetext3

So I tried setting up Sublime text editor for programming in cpp on mac , and to use formatter I added the sublimeAstyleformatter plugin and then followed these steps:
Sublime Text > Preferences > Browse packages > SublimeAstyleformatter > SublimeAStyleFormatter.sublime-settings
and inside the file I changed the autoformat_on_save to true and saved the file, but still whenver I save the cpp code, the file is not formatted.
I searched but didn't find any way out, Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Down/close voters: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help], software questions are allowed if they cover *"[...] software tools commonly used by programmers".* Sublime Text, like Vim, Emacs, VSCode, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+visual-studio-code) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic.

Comment: Does the plugin work if you use the keyboard shortcut or the Command Palette entry?

Comment: @MattDMo No, on the documentation site, the shortcut given is command + f/k , I tried using both but none of them is working, on command + f, there's find search box

Comment: Command-F/Command-K is a chord. You hold down Command, hit F, then while still holding down Command hit K. You can also hit Command-Shift-P to open the Command Palette and select one of the `SublimeAstyleFormatter` options there.

Comment: @MattDMo I followed "you hold down Command, hit F, then while still holding down Command hit K" but then too there's just find search box and in command palette there are no SublimeAstyleFormatter options

Comment: @MattDMo I tried everything same on Sublime text 3 and it worked and on Sublime text 4 it's not working, I think something's up with the newer version, anyway Thankyou so much for the help, really appreciate!

Answer (score 5):

I understand many windows users are facing the same issue on their systems too. It's probably because you may have installed fresh OS on your system.
so let's get to the solving part.
I am assuming if you are reading this answer you're already done with this step:

```
Preferences > Browse Packages > SublimeAStyleFormatter > SublimeAStyleFormatter.sublime-settings > "autoformat_on_save": true, (change false to true in line 8)
```

(*If not then do the above step after installing AsytleFormatter package in sublime, and give it a go-to check whether it started working or not*)

Now, after this, if your formatter still doesn't work there is a major chance your system doesn't have **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable - 10.040219**

here is the official link : [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable-10.040219](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999)

install this software, relaunch sublime editor and you are good to go.

PS: For confirmation do the following (I have added snap for reference [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epwsi.png)):

1. Right-click in the *file* on your sublime editor
2. Hover over *AStyleFormatter*
3. Now you will be able to see the "format" option (which previously was greyed out)

( Hope it helps to solve the issue!)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing issue with my m1 mac. Now it is resolved. What I did was open sublime text using Rosetta. Some of the sublime packages started working for me as I changed sublime text to open using Rosetta, when I click.

Follow these steps.

1. Quit Sublime text.
2. Go to Applications.
3. Right click on Sublime Text -> Get Info -> Select "Open using Rosetta" checkbox.
4. Open sublime Text again and check.

This resolved the issue for me. However, in case you do not want to go through Rosetta for sublime, then you can have Clang format Sublime Package installed; that works natively, without going through Rosetta.

Answer (score 0):

Going off the [documentation](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeAStyleFormatter), the key combos on macOS/OSX are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for format current file and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for format current selection (you had it backwards). The Command Palette commands are called `SublimeAStyleFormatter: Format Current File` and `SublimeAStyleFormatter Format Current Selection`.

After looking through the issues on the plugin's [Github repo](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter/issues), it looks like the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) is required for the plugin to work. However, seeing as you're on macOS, I'm not sure what else would be required.

Comment: Yes, I figured about the key combos, but the main thing was that in command palette there was no SublimeAStyleFormatter: Format Current File and SublimeAStyleFormatter Format Current Selection, I tried reinstalling the package but the issue continued, then I downloaded Sublime Text 3 and installed the package, now I was able to see SublimeAStyleFormatter: Format Current File and SublimeAStyleFormatter Format Current Selection in the command palette, hence I think the issue's with the latest update and compatiability

Comment: @user2780994 I think you might be right. Even though ST4 still has a Python 3.3 plugin engine, something about the interface may have changed. Feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter/issues), but since there hasn't been any update to the repo in 6 years, I doubt you'll get an official fix. A lot of Sublime packages are succumbing to bit rot. I'd still encourage you to file an issue, however, because there are numerous cases of people helping each other, so there may be a workaround. Try the [Sublime forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/), too.

Comment: Sure! will do it